# Samba issue local folders replaced my mount point

Tags: samba, mount

I have a permissions issue with a samba mount to a Windows 10 box. I am trailing FileMaker Server 19 on CentOS and want to backup the DBs to a samba mount point.

using:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=myname,password=mypassword //192.168.1.128/fmsbackup "/opt/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/Data/Backups"
```

`//192.168.1.128/fmsbackup` is the mount point on the Windows 10 box

`/opt/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/Data/Backups` is the location of the database backups

There is one folder in `fmsbackup`.

before running the mount command the FileMaker Backups folder contains the DBs backed up.

After running the mount command the FileMaker Backups folder contains the contents of fmsbackup

When I unmount the share point all is back as it should be.

Any tips on where I am going wrong?

Comment: That's normal behavior for mounting. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you want to transfer the files in `Backups` to your network share, mount it somewhere else, move your files, and then mount it in `Backups` so future backups are created directly on your network share.

Comment: The issue was that the fms deamon could not access the Backup folder after the samba mount. However I actually got it working by adding the gid and uid of the fms user & group.

Comment: If you could solve your problem, please post the solution as an answer and accept it. Otherwise your question will stay in the system as "unsolved" forever.